# JSON values serialized in Dart contain won't deserialize

Tags: c#, .net, json, flutter, dart

I am attempting to serialize some data in Flutter (Dart) and send it over to my C# .NET server for processing. The issue is that when deserializing the JSON data in .NET, it fails to recognize certain values as strings (most of the time failing to parse said string as a Boolean).

For Dart I have tried

1. dart:convert
2. The flutterdev recommended JSON parsing method

```dart
'@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
ClassName {
...
factory ClassName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ClassNameFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ClassNameToJson(this);
}
```

For C# .NET I have tried

1. `ClassName(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctx)` with mappings
2. `NewtonSoft.JsonConvert`
3. `JavascriptSerializer`

Here are some references to help piece my tired ramblings together.

- The encoded string I receive from my flutter application

```
{
    JobComplete: false,
    PolicyCount: 50,
    Removes: [{
        Raw: false,
        HalId: Removes,
        PolicyShort: REMOVES,
        PolicyLong: REMOVESTEMPLATE,
        IsClaims: false,
        CurrentPage: null,
        TotalPages: null
    }],
    Reprints: [{
        Raw: REPRINTSTEMPLATE,
        HalId: Reprints,
        PolicyShort: REPRINTS,
        PolicyLong: REPRINTSTEMPLATE,
        IsClaims: false,
        CurrentPage: null,
        TotalPages: null
    }, {
        Raw: N50000101016912NYDB2NMZ31,
        HalId: CBP3,
        PolicyShort: 16912,
        PolicyLong: 16912 NYDB2NMZ31,
        IsClaims: true,
        CurrentPage: 1,
        TotalPages: 1
    }],
    JobMeta: [],
    JobType: CLAIMS,
    TrackingId: null,
    HalIdLong: CB0625P3CR,
    HalId: CBP3,
    PrintDate: 01 / 01,
    DueDate: 01 / 05,
    MachineInfo: {
        ShortHalId: CB,
        StufferInserter: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
        FeedB: true,
        POM: false,
        JobName: CB_CLAIMS_HEART LETTER,
        JobDescription: Claims Heart Correspondence Bifold,
        MachineSetup: CLASS 1,
        SET 3,
        CRN 2 D BIFOLD,
        Envelope: 23 - 1471,
        EnvelopePOM: | POM: 23 - 1472,
        Stuffers: [{
            ID: 23 - 1450,
            POMID: 01 - 0101,
            Color: Color(0xff64ff64)
        }, {
            ID: 23 - 1453,
            POMID: 01 - 0101,
            Color: Color(0xff00dcdc)
        }, {
            ID: 23 - 1450,
            POMID: 01 - 0101,
            Color: Color(0xff64ff64)
        }, {
            ID: 23 - 1451,
            POMID: 01 - 0101,
            Color: Color(0xffff6464)
        }, {
            ID: 23 - 7043,
            POMID: 01 - 0101,
            Color: Color(0xffdcdcdc)
        }],
        SpecialInstructions: Operator report must include all damaged checks.Include LISTING with POMs,
        MachineType: BIFOLD,
        PBPSCode: 11
    }
}
```

- Error broken down by resharper https://i.gyazo.com/27969594b2d5beb4fdb58a82418133a5.png
- One fix I found by padding my string with quotes in flutter, EX: `String str = '"PaddingFix"'`
- Another fix was to rename the strings JSON acceptable Boolean values, EX: `String str = 'false'`

C# barcode class:

```cs
[Serializable()]
public class Barcode
{
    public string Raw { get; set; }
    public string HalId { get; set; }
    public string PolicyShort { get; set; }
    public string PolicyLong { get; set; }
    public bool IsClaims { get; set; }
    public int? CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int? TotalPages { get; set; }
    public string readable = "NOTASSIGNED";


    public Barcode(String raw, String halId, String policyShort, String policyLong,
        bool isClaims, int currentPage, int totalPages)
    {
        Raw = raw;
        HalId = halId;
        PolicyShort = policyShort;
        PolicyLong = policyLong;
        IsClaims = isClaims;
        CurrentPage = currentPage;
        TotalPages = totalPages;
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Raw", Raw);
        info.AddValue("HalId", HalId);
        info.AddValue("PolicyShort", PolicyShort);
        info.AddValue("PolicyLong", PolicyLong);
        info.AddValue("IsClaims", IsClaims);
        info.AddValue("CurrentPage", CurrentPage);
        info.AddValue("TotalPages", TotalPages);
    }

    public Barcode(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Raw = (string)info.GetValue("Raw", typeof(string));
        HalId = (string)info.GetValue("HalId", typeof(string));
        PolicyShort = (string)info.GetValue("PolicyShort", typeof(string));
        PolicyLong = (string)info.GetValue("PolicyLong", typeof(string));
        IsClaims = (bool)info.GetValue("IsClaims", typeof(bool));
        CurrentPage = (int)info.GetValue("CurrentPage", typeof(int));
        TotalPages = (int)info.GetValue("TotalPages", typeof(int));
    }
}
```

Last but not least, the barcode class for my Flutter application

```dart
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Barcode {
  Barcode(this.raw, this.halId,this.policyShort,this.policyLong, this.isClaims);

  @JsonKey(name: 'Raw')
  String raw;
  @JsonKey(name: 'HalId')
  String halId;
  @JsonKey(name: 'PolicyShort')
  String policyShort;
  @JsonKey(name: 'PolicyLong')
  String policyLong;
  @JsonKey(name: 'IsClaims')
  bool isClaims;
  @JsonKey(name: 'CurrentPage')
  int currentPage;
  @JsonKey(name: 'TotalPages')
  int totalPages;

  String readable = 'NOTASSIGNED';

  factory Barcode.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BarcodeFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BarcodeToJson(this);

  /*
  Barcode.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
   : raw = json['Raw'],
    halId = json['HalId'],
    policyShort = json['PolicyShort'],
    policyLong = json['PolicyLong'],
    isClaims = json['IsClaims'],
    currentPage = json['CurrentPage'],
    totalPages = json['TotalPages'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'Raw' : raw,
    'HalId' : halId,
    'PolicyShort': policyShort,
    'PolicyLong': policyLong,
    'IsClaims':isClaims,
    'CurrentPage':currentPage,
    'TotalPages':totalPages
  };*/
}
```

TL;DR: I have a Flutter class, with a `List<2ndCustomClass>`. For some reason I am having issues parsing the `2ndCustomClass` after it comes back through C#. I believe it is due to the strings not being contained in quotes, but cannot think of an elegant solution or see where my problem lies.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! I have taken the time to dress up the question to a more acceptable standard.

Comment: Greatly improved, thank you.

Comment: I can't tell you why it's happening, but that is definately not valid JSON. Only boolean and numeric primitive values can be unquoted. Everything else must be in double quotes.

Comment: The *encoded string I receive from my flutter application* is not well-formed JSON.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ or https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and you will see errors.  Are you sure that this is the "raw" JSON you are receiving, or is it the output of some visualization tool?  See https://json.org/ and https://json.org/example.html for what well-formed JSON should look like.